# 'UINavigationController?' does not have a member named 'popToRootViewControllerAnimated'

Tags: swift

Please help me to find out what's going wrong in my code.

```
@IBAction func done(sender: AnyObject) {

    let moc:NSManagedObjectContext = SwiftCoreDataHelper.managedObjectContext()

    let predicate:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "identifier ==  
                                '\(contactIdentifierString)'")
    let results:NSArray = SwiftCoreDataHelper.fetchEntities(NSStringFromClass(Contact), withPredicate: predicate, managedObjectContext: moc)

    let contact:Contact = results.lastObject as Contact

    var toDoItem:ToDoItem = SwiftCoreDataHelper.insertManagedObject(NSStringFromClass(ToDoItem), managedObjectConect: moc) as ToDoItem

    toDoItem.identifier = "\(NSDate())"
    toDoItem.dueDate = datePicked
    toDoItem.note = titleTextField.text
    toDoItem.contact = contact

    SwiftCoreDataHelper.saveManagedObjectContext(moc)

    self.navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

}

func saveContext () {
    var error: NSError? = nil
    let managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
    if managedObjectContext != nil {
// here is problem (-2/completed/ContactU/ContactU/AppDelegate.swift:54:33: 
// Cannot invoke '!=' with an argument list of type '(NSManagedObjectContext,  
//  NilLiteralConvertible)')
        if managedObjectContext.hasChanges && !managedObjectContext.save(&error) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error  
            // appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and  
            // terminate.  
           // You should not use this function in a shipping application,  
           // although it may be useful //during development.
            //println("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}

// #pragma mark - Core Data stack

// Returns the managed object context for the application.
// If the context doesn't already exist, it is created and bound to  
//   the persistent store coordinator for the application.
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext {
    if !(_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        let coordinator = persistentStoreCoordinator
        if coordinator != nil {
            _managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
            _managedObjectContext!.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        }
    }
    return _managedObjectContext!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of navigationViewController property is not UINavigationViewController, but rather **optional** of UINavigationViewController, so to make call on it you should use [optional chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html):

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

That way method will be called only if navigationController value is present (i.e. is not nil)

Comment: @Alif, what type persistentStoreCoordinator has? If it is not optional type then no need to compare it to nil at all.

Comment: can i send u screen short or  email or msg on vk please vk.com /alif 25 please or u can download and see it will be take 5m i am sure http://goo.gl/HiBi5g

Comment: there's lots of errors there :) I am not a swift expert by any means, but I guess you could use lazy evaluated properties here: https://gist.github.com/vlk/30a88e483781eafc0baf I did not test that code, but it should illustrate the general approach. Also as the type of your properties is not optional you should not check their values for nil before use - they are guaranteed to be non-nil

Comment: i am sorry yes u are rit there is lot of error i send u wrong one let me send you where only one error here is only one error https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxRTyP9zm14XdnltNDhJYnZqVmM/edit?usp=sharing thanks again

Comment: As I told - your properties are not optionals so you should not check them for nil - just use them without any checks

Comment: Plz can u rit me here that part cord here plz I try but showing me error :(

Comment: Пожалуйста Владимир ты может меня писать как ?

Comment: @Alif, as I've told - do not check if your properties are nil - use them without checks, i.e. like in this snippet http://pastie.org/9558102

Comment: hi thanks your reply did you check it becz here is same error after change :(((or or use ur code :(